# Is there a command such as "sed" in Bash scripts in C++?

Tags: c++, linux, bash, shell, sed

Currently, I'm trying to convert my Bash script to a C++ executable, but I am stuck with the `sed` command.

Here is my Bash script:

```
unset WIFIMAC
unset BTMAC

# Skip processing if MAC addresses are already written
if [ -f /data/.mac.info -a -f /data/.bt.info ]; then
    echo "MAC addresses already found."
fi

# Wait until Samsung's RIL announces MAC addresses
until [ $(expr length "$WIFIMAC") == 17 ]; do
    WIFIMAC=`getprop ril.wifi_macaddr`
    sleep 1
done

until [ $(expr length "$BTMAC") == 12 ]; do
    BTMAC=`getprop ril.bt_macaddr`
    sleep 1
done

# Set WiFi MAC address
echo $WIFIMAC >/data/.mac.info

# Convert BT MAC address to proper format
echo $BTMAC | sed 's!^M$!!;s!\-!!g;s!\.!!g;s!\(..\)!\1:!g;s!:$!!' >/data/.bt.info

exit
```

Here my try to convert it to C++ (I put comments next to Bash commands):

```
# This script will read the MAC addresses from Samsung's RIL.

unset WIFIMAC    --->      char wifimac....
unset BTMAC      --->      char btmac...

# Skip processing if MAC addresses are already written
if [ -f /data/.mac.info -a -f /data/.bt.info ]; then    ----> create file_exist(); function with fd = open... and put a smiply if return block
    echo "MAC addresses already found."
fi

# Wait until Samsung's RIL announces MAC addresses
until [ $(expr length "$WIFIMAC") == 17 ]; do           -----> while strlen(wifimac) == 17 blah blah blah....
    WIFIMAC=`getprop ril.wifi_macaddr`              -----> property_get function in cutils.h 
    sleep 1                                         -----> mdelay(1) if ım not wrong huh?.....
done

until [ $(expr length "$BTMAC") == 12 ]; do
    BTMAC=`getprop ril.bt_macaddr`                  -----> SAME COMMANDS ABOVE
    sleep 1
done

# Set WiFi MAC address
echo $WIFIMAC >/data/.mac.info                          -----> create write_string_to_path(); function with write(fd, ...)

# Convert BT MAC address to proper format
echo $BTMAC | sed 's!^M$!!;s!\-!!g;s!\.!!g;s!\(..\)!\1:!g;s!:$!!' >/data/.bt.info -----> ********HERE İS THE COMMAND "sed" *********

exit
```

I know a little bit about sed, but I don't know what it is doing here, thus I don't know which command in C++ does the same thing.

Comment: C++ has a regular expression library. What more do you need to know?

Comment: What does this conversion accomplish? Seems like BASH was the right tool for the job.

Comment: it will help if  you indicate why you are doing this. If you're just trying to make a program that people can't look at or modify, search for `shell wrapper programs`. If you have a mostly working `c++` except for the `sed` you can embed you sed call with a call to `exec(...)` (If you search around, you'll find some example how to do that). Good luck.

Comment: It might be easier if you show the input format and the desired output format as not everyone understands `sed`.

Comment: İm currently trying to read mac address from RIL and write it to path..

Comment: Unfortunately bash script is not working on my project because of that i wanted to convert it into c++ executable

Comment: @Galik here i found a documentation about sed http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html but its really so much complicated :(

Comment: @sirmordred It would be easier if you just cut and pasted some input examples and some output examples because there is no way I am going to read the `sed` manual.

Comment: Consider that the way you accomplish your goal in Bash may not be the best way to do so in C++; a direct attempt at translation may give you a worse solution. In other words, forget your Bash program, write it from scratch in C++; if they happen to look that same, that's fine.

Comment: @Galik thank you so much..will upload some i/o texts as soon as possible..will inform you when i uploaded one.. But is there a really no way to understand what sed is doing in script? Here the specific code: sed 's!^M$!!;s!\-!!g;s!\.!!g;s!\(..\)!\1:!g;s!:$!!' if we look into it seems it is replacing/deleting some letters and characters..but as i said i really dont know much about sed and its syntax..but i will upload some input output texts..thanx again..regards

Comment: It might be more sensible to work out why the Bash script is not working before trying to convert flaky code into C++ code.  The `sed` script is really doing some basic character manipulation that you can code in C++ far more conveniently than by running `sed` on a string.  IMO, running `sed` for the task would be grotesque overkill.

Comment: "bash script is not working on my project because of that i wanted to convert it into c++ ". Yikes, if  you can't get a bash script to work why do you think you'll get it to work in c++? You are very close to a solution to your problem (I think) with your script. Edit you Q to focus on fixing the `sed` call at the end. In either case,you **must** include sample data (1-2 lines) created in your chain of calls, and then show what transformations are need, including your expected output from the initial inputs. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` reads its input (in your example the string in `$BTMAC` which is echoed) and based on the expression passed to it, replaces some parts of the input data with something else (again according to the expression) and writes the result into the stdout or output file (in your case: `/data/.bt.info` file)

For example:

```
$ sed 's/replaceThis/WithThis/'
```

will replace word `replaceThis` with word `WithThis` in its input data and output the result. While both the above strings can be regular expressions.

If you are unfamiliar with it, you have to read the manual to first understand what's going on in your sed command. no one here is going to do that for you.

Now, in C++11, we have [regex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/regex) library that you can and I guess should use. If you can't use C++11 stuff, you should seek out other libraries which provide working with regex like Qt.

So in regex library of C++11, you can use [`regex_replace()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_replace) function, or search with [`regex_search()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search) and replace manually.

Comment: than you very much...will try it